# Calculating the improper integral $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\log \mid 1-x^2 \mid}{x^2} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals, riemann-integration

I tried to calculate the improper integral

$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\log \mid 1-x^2 \mid}{x^2} dx$$
using integration by parts but the function is not continuous in $x=0$ and $x=1$ and this makes trouble for finding the convergence value.

Thanks to any help for calculating the value of this integral.

Answer (score 3):

$$I=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\log|1-x^2|}{x^2} dx \\ \overset{x=\frac 1t}{=} \int_0^{\infty}\log\left|\frac{t^2-1}{t^2}\right| dt\\ =\int_0^1 \log\left(\frac{1-t^2}{t^2}\right)dt +\int_1^{\infty} \log\left(\frac{t^2-1}{t^2}\right)dt  
= I_1 + I_2$$

Now,

$$I_1\overset{\text{IBP}}=\left[t\log\left(\frac{1-t^2}{t^2}\right) \right]_0^1 -\int_0^1  \frac{2}{t^2-1}dt \\ =\lim_{t\to 1} \   \log\left(\frac{1-t^2}{t^2}\right) -\left[\log\left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)\right]_0^1 \\ =\lim_{t\to 1}\bigg[ \log\left(\frac{1-t^2} {t^2}\right)  -\log\left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)\bigg] \\ =\log (4)       $$

Similarly, $I_2= \log\left({\frac 14}\right)$

And so $$I=I_1 + I_2 = \boxed 0$$

Comment: I think there is something wrong in calculating $I_1$. You miss a negative sign, I guess.

Comment: @Masoud No, it’s correct.